# What sense is there in entropy arguments when the system can't be known to be ergodic?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, entropy, non-equilibrium

What sense does "entropy" make in non-equilibrium dynamics? What is its definition? How is the "entropy of the early universe" calculated, for example? And how can the "entropy of the universe" be taken as part of meaningful physical arguments, given that the total dynamics of the universe cannot be ergodic?

I say it cannot be ergodic because history has only taken place once so far, and I am claiming that the universe has not run through it's whole state space on the time scale that interests us.